# Tesseract, Ignore or Replace Symbols that Has Low Confidence value

Tags: c++, iterator, ocr, tesseract, symbols

I am using tesseract 3.02 and want to ignore or replace with whitespace the symbols that has Low Confidence value , such as 10 . It is like tresholding the symbols with confidence value.

The API presents just ResultIterator with RIL_SYMBOL, RIL_PARA ,RIL_TEXTLINE etc. level options. I want to iterate every symbol , on 
every page.

I want something like this ,

```
tesseract::ResultIterator *it = tess.GetIterator();
    do {
        if (it->Empty(RIL_PARA))
            continue;

            char *para_text = new_iterator ->GetUTF8Text(RIL_PARA);
            NOW ITERATE EVERY SYMBOL {
                char* symbol = some_iterator->GetUTF8Text(RIL_SYMBOL);
                if( confidence of symbol  < 35 ){

                    text += " ";
                    delete []symbol;
                }
                else{
                    text += symbol;
                    delete []symbol;
                }

            } 

    } while (it->Next(RIL_PARA));

    char* result = new char[text.length() + 1];
    strcpy(result,text.c_str());
```

I want something like this, is that possible ?